# Trigger IO install does not install correctly and does not launch the Android Emulator

Tags: android, trigger.io

I am new to Trigger IO.  I downloaded the current Toolkit and installed it on my machine.  I created an account and project, and then the first App.  When I try to use the interface to run the "Android app", everything seems to build correctly, but it will not launch the Android emulator.  I get a prompt to either select the location of the Android SDK or a prompt to download it.  If I select Download, nothing happens... the screen just flashes and I'm prompted again.  I've tried two different machines and no luck.  Can someone help me get the sample app to run using an Android emulator?  The Trigger IO does not work correctly after the install.  On a side note, if you run Trigger IO in the current version of IE (IE11), it does not render the screen correctly and it doesn't keep you logged in (you just get a blank screen).  Please help!

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

If you properly installed the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), make sure you point the Android SDK Trigger config to the subfolder named `sdk`, not just the root of the bundle. For example I have `/Users/shennyg/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/` you may be using `/Users/shennyg/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/`.

Good luck!